# Is the notation ${}^t g$ for the transpose of a linear transformation intended to be suggestive?

Tags: linear-algebra, notation

The notation ${}^t g$ for the transpose of a linear transformation is, in my view, quite unusual: otherwise (at least in many areas of math), one almost never sees subscripts or superscripts appearing on the left.

Although $g^t$ strikes me as a more natural choice of notation, I have noticed that the notation ${}^t g$ seems to be the "highbrow" choice, especially common whenever linear transformations are being emphasized rather than matrices.

Is there any reason for this other than historical accident?

Comment: I don't know about 'highbrow', but putting it on the left keeps it from being confused with exponentiation.

Comment: I guess to highlight that transposition itself is a linear operation, so it makes "pedantic" sense to have it appear before (though I find it grotesque, rather than "highbrow")...

Comment: I think the left *t* is the Bourbaki choice.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar: I see, that's where it comes from!

Comment: I always regarded the placement of it to the left as a reminder that the transpose reverses the order of multiplication. Differential geometers write coordinates as $x^i$, so I never thought that it would be confused with an exponent when it's in the upper right (since the reader ought to know what the context is).

Comment: @KConrad: Would you please elaborate? Your answer rings true, but I'm unsure of why the notation is supposed to remind me that transpose reverses the order.

Comment: Frank, it's because the superscript is appearing on the left side, which looks wrong at first.  At least this is the reasoning I made up when I first saw it.  I never discussed it with anyone.

Answer (score 3):

$$^t(g^n)=(^tg)^n$$
for $n=-1$ (inverse), $n=2$ (squaring), ... so we can just write
$$^tg^n$$

Comment: In numerical linear algebra, where transposes normally go on the right, the notation $A^{-T} := (A^{-1})^T = (A^T)^{-1}$ is quite common, and on rare occasions I have seen $A^{2T}$. So there is an analogously suggestive solution even putting transposes on the right.

Comment: (Incidentally, unfortunately one cannot extend these operations to a fully-fledged "transposition algebra" with $T^2=1$, since $A^{1+T}\neq A^{T+1}$, i.e., $A^TA\neq AA^T$.)